# robust line segment matching

Tags: c++, pattern-matching, computational-geometry

In 2D line segment matching what type of constraints can be applied?

I have 2D line segments having different lengths and orientations. These line segments are located close and around to a given line segment (let me say this as a reference line segment).  I want to find the best matched line segment for the reference line segment. The main problem is there is not any line segment which represents 100% equal length and direction to that reference line as reference has slightly change orientation than other lines. 
At the moment, I have tried with distance between line segment and and reference and angle between them. But still I cannot get the best match line segment for the given reference.

So I am looking for additional robust constraints.

thanks in advance. (This is not a homework, please)
(As i need to automate this, i put in c++)

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of error function, which describes, how good a segment matches to your reference segment. You could for example take the sum of the endpoint's distances or somehow take into account the segment's orientation. The quality of your error function also depends on the kind of data you have. You might have big variations in orientation and small variation in size or the other way round.
A good error function returns 0 for equal objects and steadily grows, the more the objects differ.